# ASP.NET ASP 2 - Prioritize Routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

For a project, I'm having dynamic pages that are retrieved from a content database. However, some pages require some additional computing. So, I thought I'd create a specific controller/view for those, and they would only be hit when they exist, otherwise, my dynamic route would catch it, and let the content controller retrieve database content for the specified route.
I hope I explained it right, but here's some code from my Global.asax that might explain it a bit more:

```
routes.MapRoute( // Default controller actions, when not found, fall back to next route?
                    "Default",                                              
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
                );

routes.MapRoute( // Catch all other? (And try to find content for those)
                    "DefaultContentRoute",              
                    "{ContentCategory}/{Content}",                        
                    new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" },  
                );
```

This is obviously not working, as I get the "Multiple types were found that match the controller named xxx" error when I'm adding a controller for content that needs extra computing. 
But I was wondering if there is any other way to achieve what I am trying to do here? (Prioritizing routes) 
I obviously want to keep my URL completely dynamic.

Lot's of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC will be confused as any URL will match both routes. Try making one of the more explicit, such as:

```
routes.MapRoute( // Catch all other? (And try to find content for those) 
                    "DefaultContentRoute",               
                    "Categories/{ContentCategory}/{Content}",                         
                    new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" },   
                ); 

routes.MapRoute( // Default controller actions, when not found, fall back to next route? 
                    "Default",                                               
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                            
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }   
                );
```

This will ensure any content will go through the default route, except for content that starts with "Categories" in the URL.
An alternative may be to abuse route constraints, and create a constraint for your ContentController route that checks if the specified content exists or not.

Comment: I figured that abusing the route constraints might be the best solution for me. Experimenting with it as we speak. (Or, type hehe)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do note that you probably want to do some caching there as it may cause a huge load on your database if checked for every request...